How to get the Element in DocumentFragment
I want to get all elements that are in the selection.
const selection = window.getSelection();
const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
const selectedNodes = [range.cloneContents().childNodes][0];

This code returns an array of Nodes inside the DocumentFragment.
The DocumentFragment is created from the text you are selecting.
The Elements that are being selected in this case are inside of a <div> with the tag ContentEditable.
The childNodes types are either text or element/span.
I want to get the element so I am able to do window.GetComputedStyle().
I tried:
selectedNodes.foreach(node => {
    console.log(node.parentNode);
});

All that came out was the DocumentFragment not the Element that I was wanting.
Also if I did node.parentElement it would return null.
When logging just the Node instead of the parent, it will log either a Text Node or Element Node.
Although it only logs an Element Node ONLY when the user highlights/selects multiple Elements.
In the case where the user is only highlighting the text of only 1 Element, the result will be one Text Node.
I have tried using the selection.commonAncestorContainer, but that includes the Element in between of two Elements even when there is no text between the two Elements.

what if you do console.log(node);

When I console.log(node) it logs: text or <span>text</span>.
In the case of logging <span>, it only logs the element ONLY when selecting multiple elements.
When you log a selection of 1 element it only logs the text NOT the parent element of the text node. @JaromandaX

It looks like this answer does what you need.

@Teemu That answer again doesn't cover the case where you are only selecting one Element.
Sure you could use the selection.commonAncestorContainer but that will return the Parent Element EVEN when that element has no selected text.

You've specifically asked "get all elements that are in the selection". A collapsed selection is also within an element. Maybe this fiddle makes it clearer. You can always filter the result, pick the one you need, or nothing.
